# Finding Critical Points - Two points on a parabola st joining line is minimised

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have that two points A,B lie on a parabola y = x^2 such that the line segment between them is always perpendicular to the tangent line at A's position. A sits at (a,a^2).

Firstly, I found the slope of the tangent line at A's position: 2a

From here, I calculated the slope of L, the line segment, which is simply -(1/2a)

I then determined the equation of L:

For y = mx + c, m is -(1/2a). Using the point (a,a^2), c was determined as a^2 + 0.5

Therefore, y = -(1/2a)x + a^2 + 0.5

I then found the position of B on the parabola. I did this through finding the intercept between y = x^2 and y = -(1/2a)x + a^2 + 0.5.

This results in B = (-a-(1/2a),(4a^4 + 4a^2 + 1)/4a^2))

I then have to write the function F(a) that gives the square of the distance between A and B as it varies with a. How do I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: No, the slope of the tangent is 2a. The slope of the line normal to the tangent is -1(2a)

Comment: Objection withdrawn!

Comment: That's OK :) Do you have an insight into what I might have done wrong though?

Comment: Everything seems right except for the $y$-value of $B$ being $a^2$. How did you conclude that?

Comment: I checked your $x$-value, it is correct. Square to get the $y$-value.

Comment: For the y value, I squared (-a-(1/2a)). I simplified -a-(1/2a) and got -a. Is this part incorrect?

Comment: It's not correct, no. For large $a$ they'll be approximately the same, but quite far apart if $a$ is small.

Comment: Ohh I've just realised that I simplified incorrectly and that it will in fact be -((2a^2 + 1)/2a). But now how do I do the last part that I mentioned?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the last answer will just be some (tedious) algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Minimizing the distance is identical to minimizing the square of the distance; this would already make life simpler.

So you have two points $A$ ($x_A,y_A$) and  $B$ ($x_B,y_B$) and then $$D^2=\Big(x_A-x_B\Big)^2+\Big(y_A-y_B\Big)^2$$ These two points are along a parabola $y=x^2$, so $$D^2=\Big(x_A-x_B\Big)^2+\Big(x_A^2-x_B^2\Big)^2$$ and you have a condition which relates $x_B$ and $x_A$. So, let $x_A=x$ and $x_B=f(x)$ which makes $$D^2=\Big(x-f(x)\Big)^2+\Big(x^2-f^2(x)\Big)^2$$ Taking the derivative  means that you have to solve $$\frac{dD^2}{dx}=2 \left(x^2-f^2(x)\right) \left(2 x-2 f(x) f'(x)\right)+2 (x-f(x))
   \left(1-f'(x)\right)=0$$ which can be written as $$\frac{dD^2}{dx}=2 \Big(x-f(x)\Big) \Big[2\Big(x+f(x)\Big)\Big(x-f(x)f'(x)\Big)+1-f'(x)\Big] =0$$ I did not check your calculations but if, as you wrote, $$f(x)=-x-\frac{1}{2x}$$ you then have to solve $$\frac{dD^2}{dx}=-\frac{1}{4 x^5}-\frac{3}{2 x^3}+8 x=0$$ which reduces to $$32 x^6-6 x^2-1=0$$ which is a cubic equation in $x^2$. Factorization gives $$32y^3-6y-1=(4y+1)^2(2y-1)$$ so the only acceptable root is $y=\frac{1}{2}$ from which $$x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$